# PyMOL: Get sequence of selection

Tags: alignment, pymol

I have made a selection of residues like this:

```
fetch 1bsx
select interface_1bsx, byres((1bs and chain A) within 5A of (1bsx and chain X))
```

How do I get the sequence of `interface_1bsx`?

Comment: Can you `pyp` `pymol` through the terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `iterate` command ([pymol wiki](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Iterate)):

```
iterate interface_1bsx, resn
```

Or if you prefer to have it in a python list:

```
residues = []
iterate interface_1bsx, residues.append(resn)
print(residues)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(cmd.get_fastastr('sele'))
```

Maybe this function didn't exist back in the day.

https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Get_fastastr